# Open FaceTime programmatically without any number or apple id - iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, facetime

Till iOS8, I was able to open the FaceTime app from my App using the below code.

If I have the number, A call will be directly made, if it is nil, it would just open up FaceTime.

But since iOS8, in case of empty number, FaceTime don't open at all.

```
NSString *temp =@"facetime://";
        if(number && number.length>0){
            temp = [temp stringByAppendingString:number];
        }
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS accepts the following URL:

```
facetime://14085551234 
facetime://user@example.com
```

According to their [FaceTime Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html).

If FaceTime doesn't launch with empty number, it may just be their way of cleaning up old code.

Comment: Similar issues when using an anchor tag - the app opens, but the number/email to be called is not passed to the app. Thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749122/apple-facetime-url-scheme-not-initiating-call